# Should I rely on the Config.groovy when creating unit tests in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

According to the Grails documentation

> Unit tests are typically run without the presence of physical
>   resources that involve I/O such databases, socket connections or
>   files.

However, when I run my tests with the Grails cmd line tool it includes the Config.groovy meaning that in my tested code I have...

```
Integer daysToRetain = grailsApplication.config.com.gleason.assignmentRetentionDays as Integer
```

this resolves correctly without having to mock it. Also in my unit test I have the following...

```
import grails.util.Holders
...
Integer daysToRetain = Holders.config.com.gleason.assignmentRetentionDays as Integer
```

Why does grails load the Config.groovy if it is not a convention to use it? Also, what other files are OK to rely on?

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests in Grails will bootstrap a minimally viable Grails runtime environment. This means configuration, but not necessarily loading the components or plugins that pertain to persistence (ie. hibernate datasources).

The Grails documentation doesn't speak to not being able to get a handle on the configuration during unit tests, given that the config is embedded within your project. Rather, it's speaking more to not necessarily having runtime server-local filesystem resources during your unit testing (esp if you're running in CI).

```
Also, what other files are OK to rely on?
```

Presumably anything resource within your project.

Comment: These are personally set properties so they are not really part of the minimal Grails runtime so does that matter? Isn't it confusing to load up parts of the Config file and not others?

Comment: The whole config file is loaded, not just parts of it. It is the plugin ecosystem that is not 100% initialized in a unit spec.

Answer (score 1):

i personally would mock it out, because of one of the following reasons:

If you go the isolation path of unit testing, then obviously `Config.groovy` would not be the unit under test. So this means `Config.groovy` is an external dependency and to let the test not depend on an external dependency that could possibly change is a benefit, because then it could not break by a mistakenly Config.groovy change.

If you use grails plugins to decompose your grails app, then you the little wired situation, that in test mode, you have to define your configs in the plugin, because the unit-tests run in plugin local and in a run-app situation you have to set them in the app, because config.groovy is by default not exposed from the plugin (this is obviously not a big deal, but anyway).

But the other point here that i see is, that by mocking it out, you make it explicitly in your test, that you a expecting a certain path from the config (like `com.gleason.assignmentRetentionDays`), that you would otherwise you would just have to know, because its in your implementation.

Additionally it becomes more clear, when only reading the test, what values are set for this paticular config setting. This is not in all cases important, but sometimes it could be nice to know when reading the test.